# Wonderware History Tags

Tags: excel, historian, wonderware

When I run my function to retrieve the history values in Wondereware into Excel it only loads 4 of the 50 tags.

I have tried to select the cells that have the tag names in it and it seems that it only takes 4 of the tag names and I need all 50.

```
=wwWideHistory3("LEWC2012INSQL", AFTagBinding,"Row7",AFStartBinding,AFEndBinding,254,0,0,0,0,3,0,"",3,"",-1,0,"","NoFilter",16384)
```

The 4 tags that it loads. I need 50 tags.

```
DateTime            L2_PT6130   L2_PT6230   NU_DC01_DX01_DISPLAY    NU_DC01_DX02_DISPLAY
6/1/19 6:00:00 AM   2.255943775 3.29255867  0.039721143             -0.231841758
6/2/19 10:00:00 AM  2.26124382  3.646864653 0.084306099             -0.209954605
6/3/19 2:00:00 PM   2.498756409 3.312580585 0.042153049             -0.206712067
6/4/19 6:00:00 PM   2.703880787 3.238382339 0.027561609             -0.233463034
6/5/19 10:00:00 PM  2.20412302  3.113344669 0.091601819             -0.229409859
6/7/19 2:00:00 AM   2.044145584 2.985558987 2.3581388                0.968709469
6/8/19 6:00:00 AM   2.187830925 3.223267794 2.323281527              0.663099885
```

Comment: Did you check if another historian client, for example historian trend, shows any data for the other tags?

Comment: yes i checked on the server i now got tags to load but when i change the date on AFBindings start date and end date i get a Query error.

Comment: I know it is a simple question, but are you sure that the rest of the 50 tags is set to historize, i.e. is the "log data", "Historize tag" or "Enable History" check-boxes on each tag checked?

Comment: what i need to get working is have the tags load into excel when the user enters the start date and end date and the push a button that has VBA code  which i dont know how to set up the code to do that yes but essentially I want it to load the wwWideHistory3 formula in the next cell and execute it to load the values not sure if anyone can help me.